# Elasticsearch exact match only for specific fields on multi_match fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, search

Im trying to search only on the following fields:

1. name (product name)
2. vendor.username
3. vendor.name
4. categories_name

But the results is to wide, I want the results to be exactly what user is typed.

Example:

I type `Cloth A` I want the result to be **exactly** `Cloth A` not something else contain `Cloth` or `A`

Here is my attempt:

```

```
GET /products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "cloth A", 
          "fields": [
            "name",
            "vendor.name",
            "vendor.username",
            "categories_name"
          ] 
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
          "is_available": true
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "is_ready": true
          }
        },
        {
          "missing": {
            "field": "deleted_at"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```

How do I do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `multi_match`

```
"multi_match": {
  "type": "best_fields"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works:

```
"multi_match": {
  "type": "phrase"
 }
```